# PHP Preg Replace on SVG file causes Segmentation Fault

Tags: php, regex, svg, segmentation-fault, preg-replace

When I try run this command on my SVG file, the browser says no data has been received and I get an error in my Apache log file.

```
preg_match("/(<g(\s|\S)*?<\/g>)/i", $SVG, $Matches);
```

My SVG file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-h8Ddvp85rwTl8zTTN0bTlBbDQ/view?usp=sharing).

And the actual error that I'm getting is this

> [core:notice] [pid 20852] AH00052: child pid 31338 exit signal
>   Segmentation fault (11)

What have I done wrong here and how do I fix this?

Comment: You can't be serious with the close vote? I'm using the `preg_replace` function and getting an error that I don't know how to resolve in the context that I'm receiving the error in. In what possible way is that not a programming question?

Comment: Does the regex work if you test it on your local machine? Can your provide the content of `$SVG` (Googles asking for permissions to view it)?

Comment: Try to strip down the SVG to the bare minimum when it still fails.

Comment: svg is xml, I don't know why you obtain a segment fault, but the good approach is to use an xml parser, for example DOMDocument or the combo XMLReader/XMLWriter, but not `preg_replace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [PHP DOM functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to parse XML files. [There is a good reason, why you shouldn't use RegEX to parse XML :-)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4382892)

Since you are looking for all `<g ...></g>` tags, you can do this like this:

```
$xdoc = new DOMDocument;
// load your .svg
$xdoc->Load('0057b8.svg');
// get all "g"-tags
$gTags = $xdoc->getElementsByTagName('g');
// since the return is a DOMNodeList, we loop through all (even if it's only 1)
foreach($gTags as $gTag) {
    // and here we can e.g. get the attributes
    echo $gTag->getAttribute('transform') . PHP_EOL;
    echo $gTag->getAttribute('fill') . PHP_EOL;
    echo $gTag->getAttribute('stroke') . PHP_EOL;
    // or set a new attribute
    $gTag->setAttribute('stroke-width', '5');
}
```

The g-tags will be [DOMElements](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php), so you can read in the reference to get all possible methods on them.

Comment: Yes! This was the sort of exact thing I was looking for, I know the woes of parsing XML/HTML with regex but I couldn't seem to find another way to do it, but this worked perfectly. Thanks!